# How to record whole incoming call from IVR flow twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, ivr, twilio-programmable-chat

[Flow of IVR script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc7Kf.jpg) I am working on Twilio studio for an incoming call, now I have setup everything except one thing that is to record the whole incoming call. I have done the recording of outgoing successfully but can't find a way to record an incoming call on IVR flow with Twilio studio. Anyone with Twilio IVR experience who can help?

Comment: I am using flow https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/flows/, here we don't code we only build flow and test it by phone number. 
Our script is complicated so we shifted to flow instead of write code whole script which makes some serious confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's not possible to record the entire incoming call, however when you get to the stage of connecting the incoming caller to an agent or a conference that is the point at which you can start the recording.

At that stage, you want to turn on the "Record call" switch on the "Connect call to" widget.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**You should buy a new number in Twillio .After you forward a call through studio through widgets(connect call to widget) and link with your actual flow then that will work 100% and records the whole call .**